# import data in workbench mysql

Tags: excel, csv, syntax-error, mysql-workbench

i can't import data in description of his video in benchwork , mysql https://youtu.be/qfyynHBFOsM?list=PLUaB-1hjhk8FE_XZ87vPPSfHqb6OcM0cF who made it before?

import data from excel to workbench mysql

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.